# Created table in Impala using S3 location but unable to get data into table

Tags: amazon-s3, impala

I have created a table with Impala using an S3 location along with a partition, but no data is populating while querying. How can I overcome this?

```
create table t(id int, name string) partitioned by (year int)
stored as avaro
location 's3a://impala-/dir1/';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no data is populating while querying"? Is there data already in that S3 location that you are wanting to query? What is your query? Or, are you trying to INSERT information into that table? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more detail, with examples.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use an [External Table](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_create_table.html):

> By default, Impala creates an "internal" table, where Impala manages the underlying data files for the table, and physically deletes the data files when you drop the table. If you specify the `EXTERNAL` clause, Impala treats the table as an "external" table, where the data files are typically produced outside Impala and queried from their original locations in HDFS, and Impala leaves the data files in place when you drop the table.

Therefore, try this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE t(id int, name string) partitioned by (year int)
STORED AS avro
LOCATION 's3a://impala-/dir1/';
```

Comment: even for external also data is not populating after giving location